# What does printDebugData(JTabble table) do?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i am trying to read source code to have more understanding of JTable but there is method i don't get why they write it method name is `private void printDebugData(JTable table)`

[the link for the code here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java)

Comment: If it's private, you can't use it so it doesn't matter. Presumably it's something the developers created while they were working on a JTable bug. It shouldn't have been javadoc'd at all.

Comment: It is NOT javadoc'd -- OP is looking at source code.

Comment: sorry i did not get what op mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are referring to is part of an Oracle tutorial that is designed to help programmers understand how to use the `JTable` class.

The method `private void printDebugData(JTable table)` in this program takes a `JTable` as a parameter and prints it to the console (in a plain-text format).

This method seems to have been implemented to help programmers optionally see the data in the table in the console, but only if called within this class (as `private` limits the visibility of this method to only this class). To see the output of this method, simply change the line:

```
private boolean DEBUG = false;
```

to:

```
private boolean DEBUG = true;
```

to see the contents of the `JTable` in plain-text output to the console.